# Maps webapp with satellite view updated more often than Google Maps

Tags: windows, maps

I am a great fan of Google Maps and I have been using it for many months, but it's not providing updated map views in the Satellite view.

For example: recently a few new buildings have been built in my neighbourhood, but those changes aren't reflected in Google Maps satellite view, and it shows pictures of at least a few months ago.

Can anyone suggest me a good substitute for Google Maps which updates satellite views more frequently?

Comment: Google maps is updated periodically and you can report or sometimes fix errors via Google Map Maker https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873?hl=en&rd=1

Comment: @SteveBarnes It is only for classic view. I use Satellite view always.

Comment: Microsoft also have a maps service based on Bing... http://www.bing.com/maps/

Comment: The obvious approach seems to be to use something based on Open Street Maps and to contribute updates yourself.  http://www.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: You didn't give a lot of constraints (where? what's your budget?) but [NearMap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NearMap) does exactly this.

Comment: Do you need a gratis tool or would it be okay to pay for the service (how much?) What resolution do you need? Online or Offline? "Alternative to" questions don't work well if you don't state what requirements you have.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.